# Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader

Tags: java, android, itext, sign, pkcs#12

I tried to develop an android application which sign a pdf file using iText. The project runs perfectly on API levels, however, I'm getting some problems on emulators. When I load up the application on an emulator, I get this issue:

```
02-25 15:33:25.705: W/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: **unable to resolve static field 736 (CMS) in Lcom/itextpdf/text/pdf/security/MakeSignature$CryptoStandard**;
02-25 15:33:25.715: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0060
02-25 15:33:25.715: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: dead code 0x0062-0069 in Lcom/exampl/exemp/signP;.signat ()V
02-25 15:33:25.735: E/dalvikvm(3138): **Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader**', referenced from method com.exampl.exemp.signP.sign
02-25 15:33:25.735: W/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 423 (Lcom/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader;) in Lcom/exampl/exemp/signP;
02-25 15:33:25.745: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
02-25 15:33:25.745: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: dead code 0x0002-004f in Lcom/exampl/exemp/signP;.sign (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/security/cert/Certificate;Ljava/security/PrivateKey;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/itextpdf/text/pdf/security/MakeSignature$CryptoStandard;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
02-25 15:33:25.775: W/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/pkcs/PrivateKeyInfo;)
02-25 15:33:25.775: I/dalvikvm(3138): Could not find method org.spongycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo.getPrivateKeyAlgorithm, referenced from method org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.getPrivateKey
02-25 15:33:25.785: W/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4562: Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/pkcs/PrivateKeyInfo;.getPrivateKeyAlgorithm ()Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/x509/AlgorithmIdentifier;
02-25 15:33:25.796: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-25 15:33:25.796: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: dead code 0x0005-0018 in Lorg/spongycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider;.getPrivateKey (Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/pkcs/PrivateKeyInfo;)Ljava/security/PrivateKey;
02-25 15:33:25.796: W/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/x509/SubjectPublicKeyInfo;)
02-25 15:33:25.815: I/dalvikvm(3138): Could not find method org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getAlgorithm, referenced from method org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.getPublicKey
02-25 15:33:25.815: W/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4870: Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/x509/SubjectPublicKeyInfo;.getAlgorithm ()Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/x509/AlgorithmIdentifier;
02-25 15:33:25.825: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-25 15:33:25.825: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: dead code 0x0005-0018 in Lorg/spongycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider;.getPublicKey (Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/x509/SubjectPublicKeyInfo;)Ljava/security/PublicKey;
02-25 15:33:25.875: W/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: unable to resolve static field 856 (id_PBKDF2) in Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/pkcs/PKCSObjectIdentifiers;
02-25 15:33:25.875: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x00dd
02-25 15:33:25.875: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: dead code 0x00df-090e in Lorg/spongycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider;.setup ()V
02-25 15:33:25.885: W/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/ASN1ObjectIdentifier;)
02-25 15:33:25.905: W/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/ASN1ObjectIdentifier;)
02-25 15:33:25.935: I/dalvikvm(3138): Could not find method org.spongycastle.util.Strings.toLowerCase, referenced from method org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.config.ProviderConfigurationPermission.calculateMask
02-25 15:33:25.935: W/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: unable to resolve static method 10961: Lorg/spongycastle/util/Strings;.toLowerCase (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
02-25 15:33:25.935: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0002
02-25 15:33:25.935: D/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: dead code 0x0005-0057 in Lorg/spongycastle/jcajce/provider/config/ProviderConfigurationPermission;.calculateMask (Ljava/lang/String;)I
02-25 15:33:25.955: W/dalvikvm(3138): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lorg/spongycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProviderConfiguration;
02-25 15:33:25.955: W/dalvikvm(3138): Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Lorg/spongycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider;
02-25 15:33:25.975: D/AndroidRuntime(3138): Shutting down VM
02-25 15:33:25.975: W/dalvikvm(3138): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at com.exampl.exemp.signP.signat(signP.java:66)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at com.exampl.exemp.MainActivity.editText(MainActivity.java:107)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at com.exampl.exemp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.<clinit>(BouncyCastleProvider.java:53)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     ... 16 more
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.spongycastle.util.Strings
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.config.ProviderConfigurationPermission.calculateMask(ProviderConfigurationPermission.java:64)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.config.ProviderConfigurationPermission.<init>(ProviderConfigurationPermission.java:58)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProviderConfiguration.<clinit>(BouncyCastleProviderConfiguration.java:16)
02-25 15:33:26.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     ... 17 more
02-25 15:38:26.145: I/Process(3138): Sending signal. PID: 3138 SIG: 9
```

Remark: I tried the same code in sample java and it works fine.

Comment: Actually, there are plenty of references to SpongyCastle. Did you include SpongyCastle in your APK?

Comment: Yes I include it. I used scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2, scpkix-jdk15on-1.47.0.2 and sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2

Comment: Please any idea M. Bruno.

Comment: Looking at your new question, I see that you now also agree that SpongyCastle is missing ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034635/could-not-find-class-org-spongycastle-jce-provider-bouncycastleprovider I'll answer there.